# React Native, Django and Google places integration

Tags: django, react-native, google-maps, google-places-api

I have an app I'm building with react native and django... I created a post model which stores location coordinates, now I want a situation where a user tries to create a post, they will use google places to get the address they want. Then it should store the coordinates in the backend.

And also in the frontend, it should not display coordinates from the backend but the address as it is from google places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Google Places Autocomplete](http://%60https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places-autocomplete%60) package to handle this information for you. [Here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResponses) you have a response example from the Google Places API that shows the coordinates as well as the Place ID from the performed search. In the frontend, you can use the same package to display the address. Here's an example:

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
   placeholder='Search'
   onPress={(data, details = null) => {
      // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
         console.log(data, details);
   }}
   query={{
      key: 'YOUR API KEY',
      language: 'en',
    }}
    predefinedPlaces={[{
       description: 'Home',
       geometry: { location: { lat: 48.8152937, lng: 2.4597668 } },
    }]} />
```

Comment: Should you put your API key in your frontend? Sounds like a security issue